# Return the quotation marks in return statement

Tags: python-3.x

I made a function that returns a string as shown below but I was wondering how do I keep the double quotes for the quote?

```
def quote_maker(quote, name, year):
''' (string, string, number)-> None
Returns a sentence displaying in what given year the
given name of a person said the given quote.
'''
return (' In '+ str(year) +', a person called '+ name +' said: '+ quote)
```

For example my function returns:

```
 quote_maker("Everything should be made as simple as possible but not simpler.", "Albert Einstein", 1933)

'In 1933, a person called Albert Einstein said: Everything should be made as simple as possible but not simpler.'
```

Instead of: (with double quotes)

```
'In 1933, a person called Albert Einstein said: "Everything should be made as simple as possible but not simpler."'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape characters (done with `\`) that have a special meaning to treat them as characters:

`" this is quoted: \"example\" "`

represents the string:

> this is quoted: "example"

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to use string formating. And return the variable.

```
sentence = 'In {0}, a person called {1} said: "{2}".'.format(year, name, quote)
```

For complicated string you should use escape characters. For more details [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)